# hadoop namenode not running on 2 node cluster of two ec2 instances:Error FSNamesystem initialization failed

Tags: java, hadoop, amazon-ec2

I am trying to setup two node hadoop (1.1.1)cluster with 2 individual ec2 instances. When i start ./start-all.sh, all deamons are running fine on two nodes except namenode on master node. I configured it such that one node acts as both master and slave and other node only as slave. I checked name node log and i see below message: I ran perfectly ./hadoop namenode -format and even then i am getting this error saying that FSNameSystem initialization failed and namenode not formatted. Please help.

```
2015-07-21 14:18:24,374 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsConfig: loaded properties from hadoop-metrics2.properties
2015-07-21 14:18:24,384 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSourceAdapter: MBean for source MetricsSystem,sub=Stats registered.
2015-07-21 14:18:24,387 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSystemImpl: Scheduled snapshot period at 10 second(s).
2015-07-21 14:18:24,387 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSystemImpl: NameNode metrics system started
2015-07-21 14:18:24,595 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSourceAdapter: MBean for source ugi registered.
2015-07-21 14:18:24,598 WARN org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSystemImpl: Source name ugi already exists!
2015-07-21 14:18:24,602 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSourceAdapter: MBean for source jvm registered.
2015-07-21 14:18:24,602 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSourceAdapter: MBean for source NameNode registered.
2015-07-21 14:18:24,616 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.util.GSet: VM type       = 64-bit
2015-07-21 14:18:24,616 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.util.GSet: 2% max memory = 17.78 MB
2015-07-21 14:18:24,616 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.util.GSet: capacity      = 2^21 = 2097152 entries
2015-07-21 14:18:24,616 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.util.GSet: recommended=2097152, actual=2097152
2015-07-21 14:18:24,631 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem: fsOwner=ubuntu
2015-07-21 14:18:24,631 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem: supergroup=supergroup
2015-07-21 14:18:24,631 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem: isPermissionEnabled=true
2015-07-21 14:18:24,635 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem: dfs.block.invalidate.limit=100
2015-07-21 14:18:24,635 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem: isAccessTokenEnabled=false accessKeyUpdateInterval=0 min(s), accessTokenLifetime=0 min(s)
2015-07-21 14:18:24,662 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem: Registered FSNamesystemStateMBean and NameNodeMXBean
2015-07-21 14:18:24,692 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode: Caching file names occuring more than 10 times
2015-07-21 14:18:24,701 ERROR org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem: FSNamesystem initialization failed.
java.io.IOException: NameNode is not formatted.
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSImage.recoverTransitionRead(FSImage.java:330)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSDirectory.loadFSImage(FSDirectory.java:100)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.initialize(FSNamesystem.java:411)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.<init>(FSNamesystem.java:379)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.initialize(NameNode.java:277)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.<init>(NameNode.java:529)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.createNameNode(NameNode.java:1403)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.main(NameNode.java:1412)
2015-07-21 14:18:24,702 ERROR org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode: java.io.IOException: NameNode is not formatted.
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSImage.recoverTransitionRead(FSImage.java:330)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSDirectory.loadFSImage(FSDirectory.java:100)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.initialize(FSNamesystem.java:411)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.<init>(FSNamesystem.java:379)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.initialize(NameNode.java:277)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.<init>(NameNode.java:529)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.createNameNode(NameNode.java:1403)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.main(NameNode.java:1412)

2015-07-21 14:18:24,702 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode: SHUTDOWN_MSG:
```

Comment: Interestingly, after running ./hadoop namenode -format it displays below message, which clearly shows formatting is successful.

 Re-format filesystem in hadoopName ? (Y or N) Y
15/07/22 06:53:58 INFO util.GSet: VM type       = 64-bit
......
15/07/22 06:53:59 INFO common.Storage: Storage directory hadoopName has been successfully formatted.
15/07/22 06:53:59 INFO namenode.NameNode: SHUTDOWN_MSG: 

But, namenode log shows, Namenode is not formatted. 
How can both messages be contradicting each other..?? Is it a bug or any thing wrong on my side?

Comment: Can you try sudo -u hdfs hadoop namenode format

Comment: Amal , Can you give the exact command? Do you mean "sudo ./hadoop namenode -format" ? In that case, I tried this also, but no difference.

Comment: The command I mentioned was not the one that you executed. Why are you using ./hadoop ? Add the hadoop to the PATH and execute the command sudo -u hdfs hadoop namenode format. Before executing this, revisit your configurations. Seems like some problem with your namenode and datanode directories. Specify absolute path instead of just a directory name. Ensure that those directories exist

Comment: Thanks Armal. Now its working fine. Never i thought this 'absolute path' for the directories has such an impact. I just changed it to abs path and it requires even the dir should have 755 permissions.
Thanks a lot for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Stop all the daemons.. Try defining these two properties dfs.data.dir & dfs.name.dir in hdfs-site.xml file.

start all daemons

Comment: I have mentioned that already. <property>
      <name>dfs.data.dir</name>
      <value>hdfsData/</value>
     <final>true</final>
   </property>

   <property>
      <name>dfs.name.dir</name>
      <value>hdfsName/</value>
<final>true</final>
 </property>

Comment: Provide the complete path. Absolute path starts with /. I am not seeing any / in the path you mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

Log showing that namenode is not formatted.
Try formatting namenode
$sudo hdfs namenode format

Comment: I have already formatted and same i mentioned in my post also. Still its not running only namenode. What else could be the reason. Starting and stopping all the daemons from master works well except namenode running up.